# Select nextval from a sequence with a variable name

Tags: oracle, sequence

I'm working in an app where each user has an Id which is a consecutive number from a sequence, the sequence is not always the same.

Let's say you have the sequence A with nextval set to 8 and sequence B with nextval set to 5. The app has to tell which sequence to use based in a set of rules, so the next entry can have the id 5 or 8 (It won't have any contraint issue beacuse the primary key is in another field). I'd like to use a single query like

```
SELECT NEXTVAL FROM ALL_SEQUENCES WHERE SEQUENCE_NAME = "";
```

But i can't figure out if thats even possible.

I wouldn't like to concatenate the sequence name inside my app code as it breaks the pattern that i'm using for the rest of my queries.

Comment: You will need to write a function where you pass the sequence name. The function then can use dynamic SQL to query the sequence and return the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name suggested you can  create a function to get the next value like,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION next_val(
         sequence_name IN VARCHAR2
         )RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS
     v_nextval INTEGER;
     v_select VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
     v_select := 'select '||sequence_name||'.nextval from dual';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_select INTO v_nextval;

     RETURN v_nextval;
END;
```

Comment: But is there any way to use <sequence_name> as variable so it can be A.nextval or B.nextval within the same query?. A case statement is not an option since i can't guarantee that sequence_name will remain the same (it is defined by the user).

Comment: In that case you can create a function to do this, Please have a look at my updated answer.